# Database in server for Android application

Tags: android, database

I am doing a research on how databases work in android applications and i have been confused. I have experience with PHP/MySQL databases for websites where i have a database in phpmyadmin and i can access those dbs via php/mysql queries. I thought it would be like that for android apps but it seems that i was wrong. I have also experience with MongoDB and Java but for local side purposes.

My question is what is the equivalent method in Android applications?

I have read about SQLite and what i understood is that it works for local purposes. I expect a lot of data coming in my application so this would not work for me.

So, what i need to know is how can i have a database on a server (like phpmyadmin in web and mysql) for an android application and how can i access this database.

I am using android studio so Java is the programming lanuage. Could i just communicate with the database in phpmyadmin via Java?

Any tutorials, books are very very welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use H2 for my server-side SQL. It plays very nicely with java and has some useful tools for viewing and editing databases.
You can have your android application communicate though http post methods and use PHP to access databases. (However, I have little experience with PHP, and am not the person to ask about that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't such thing as phpMyAdmin for Android databases.

The only way of browsing the database in a "phpMyAdmin way" is pulling the database file from the emulator/device and open it with a program like this: http://sqlitebrowser.org/.

The database file can be found following these steps:

Go to the DDMS File Explorer --> data --> data --> "Your Package Name" --> pull file from device/emulator.

The other way of viewing the data from the db is browsing it via command line. Please check this link: http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

But, if you will have a lot of data, I think it's better to use an API (that might be done with PHP/MySQL).

Comment: Thanks Dan. I think i'll go with this solution :) cheers

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend Firebase 
http://firebase.com is the best ever NoSQL database for mobile development, and the magic thing is **YOU DONT HAVE TO DEVELOP WEBSERVICES**, yes, its a dream. Firebase changed my life, I'm a new man.

Who also accept Firebase as your savior?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you have a lot of data, SQLite may be a wrong solution.
If you want to use a MySQL database, then you should be able to add some PHP pages on a web server and call it from Android. the PHP will contain the MySQL code to read or write on the MySQL database. Json is a good format to exchange data between PHP and Android.

On Android side, have a look at okhttp3 libraries to communicate with PHP via json.